# Mini-Max Sum Coding Challenge Python

Tags: python

I worked on this coding question as practice earlier: "Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers."

I have a tendency to overcomplicate things. This is my solution and after researching I found how simple the actual solution was. What are some tips on thinking of the best minimalistic approach to a problem?

```
#My solution
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    countList = []
    currentIndex = 0
    max_sum = 0
    min_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j, number in enumerate(arr):
            if j != currentIndex:
                    countList.append(number)
        if sum(countList) > max_sum:
            max_sum = sum(countList)
        if i == 0:
            min_sum = sum(countList)
        elif sum(countList) < min_sum:
            min_sum = sum(countList)
        currentIndex += 1
        countList = []
    print(min_sum, max_sum)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    miniMaxSum(arr)
```

Comment: Sort the five integers.  The maximum sum is obviously the four largest values, and the minimum sum is obviously the four smallest values.

Comment: Add all the integers together. You can avoid sorting by tracking min and max in the loop. Subtract the minimum for the max sum, subtract the max for the min sum. Same idea as this guy above me.

Comment: It beats me why my brain did not allow me to think of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution, if you prefer:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    mini = min(arr)
    maxi = max(arr)

    mini_sum = sum(arr) - maxi
    maxi_sum= sum(arr)-mini

    print(f'The minimum sum is {mini_sum}, the maximum sum is {maxi_sum}')



miniMaxSum([2,1,3,10,4])
```

The output (for clarity I have changed the print requirement):
[image]

Not sure if this avoids sorting by using min and max functions, but if it didn't you could loop through and accomplish it with the sort. BrokenBenchmark's answer is the most concise of course though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using `sorted()`, list slicing, and `sum()` (This is the simplest solution if "simple" == "minimizing number of lines of code", though this principle isn't always true):

```py
print(sum(sorted(input_list)[:-1]), sum(sorted(input_list[1:])))
```

In general, you shouldn't try to aim for exactly matching a posted solution on your first try. You are solving the problem for the first time, while the solution likely has been edited, revised, refactored, etc.. Improving your ability to write simpler solutions often comes from exposure to similar problems and experience with using various language features, which takes takes time and practice.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will definitely keep this in mind and keep practicing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an optimised version that loop only one time through the array consider this simplest solution, The idea is to subtract the min and the max from total sum to find each sum

```py
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    minNum = float('inf')
    maxNum = float('-inf')
    totalSum = 0
    for num in arr:
        totalSum+= num
        if num < minNum:
            minNum=num
        if num > maxNum:
            maxNum = num
        
    minSum = totalSum - maxNum # Subtract the maximum value to get the minimum sum
    maxSum = totalSum - minNum # Subtract the minimum value to get the maximum sum
 
    print(minSum, maxSum)
```